# Mysql install Error: Could not find OpenSSL on the system

Tags: mysql

im following this guideline to install `mysql`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/5.7/en/binary-installation.html

here is list of command:

```sh
$> groupadd mysql
$> useradd -r -g mysql -s /bin/false mysql
$> cd /usr/local
$> tar zxvf /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz
$> ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql
$> cd mysql
$> mkdir mysql-files
$> chown mysql:mysql mysql-files
$> chmod 750 mysql-files
$> bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
$> bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup
$> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
# Next command is optional
```

When i run to this command `bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup` then i got error:
`[ERROR]   Could not find OpenSSL on the system`

I run this command to install openssl : `yum install openssl-devel` 
it look ok:

```sh
Total                                                                                                            6.0 MB/s | 6.5 MB  00:00:01
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : libcom_err-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          1/28
  Updating   : keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.4.alios7.x86_64                                                                                        2/28
  Updating   : libsepol-2.5-10.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                              3/28
  Updating   : libselinux-2.5-14.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          4/28
  Updating   : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                     5/28
  Updating   : krb5-libs-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          6/28
  Installing : libkadm5-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           7/28
  Installing : libsepol-devel-2.5-10.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                        8/28
  Installing : keyutils-libs-devel-1.5.8-3.4.alios7.x86_64                                                                                  9/28
  Updating   : libss-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                              10/28
  Installing : libcom_err-devel-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                   11/28
  Updating   : e2fsprogs-libs-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                     12/28
  Installing : pcre-devel-8.32-15.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          13/28
  Installing : libselinux-devel-2.5-14.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                   14/28
  Installing : libverto-devel-0.2.5-4.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                      15/28
  Installing : krb5-devel-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                        16/28
  Installing : zlib-devel-1.2.7-16.2.alios7.x86_64                                                                                         17/28
  Installing : 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                   18/28
  Updating   : e2fsprogs-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          19/28
  Cleanup    : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                    20/28
  Cleanup    : krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                         21/28
  Cleanup    : e2fsprogs-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                            22/28
  Cleanup    : e2fsprogs-libs-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                       23/28
  Cleanup    : libss-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                                24/28
  Cleanup    : libselinux-2.5-12.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           25/28
  Cleanup    : libsepol-2.5-8.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                            26/28
  Cleanup    : libcom_err-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           27/28
  Cleanup    : keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                       28/28
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                    1/28
  Verifying  : e2fsprogs-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           2/28
  Verifying  : krb5-libs-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          3/28
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                     4/28
  Verifying  : libss-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                               5/28
  Verifying  : keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.4.alios7.x86_64                                                                                        6/28
  Verifying  : krb5-devel-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                         7/28
  Verifying  : libcom_err-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          8/28
  Verifying  : zlib-devel-1.2.7-16.2.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          9/28
  Verifying  : libverto-devel-0.2.5-4.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                      10/28
  Verifying  : libselinux-devel-2.5-14.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                   11/28
  Verifying  : libcom_err-devel-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                   12/28
  Verifying  : libsepol-devel-2.5-10.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                       13/28
  Verifying  : libsepol-2.5-10.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                             14/28
  Verifying  : pcre-devel-8.32-15.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          15/28
  Verifying  : libkadm5-1.15.1-51.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                          16/28
  Verifying  : libselinux-2.5-14.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                         17/28
  Verifying  : keyutils-libs-devel-1.5.8-3.4.alios7.x86_64                                                                                 18/28
  Verifying  : e2fsprogs-libs-1.43.5-8.3.alios7.x86_64                                                                                     19/28
  Verifying  : libss-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                                20/28
  Verifying  : keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                       21/28
  Verifying  : libselinux-2.5-12.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           22/28
  Verifying  : libcom_err-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           23/28
  Verifying  : libsepol-2.5-8.1.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                            24/28
  Verifying  : e2fsprogs-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                            25/28
  Verifying  : e2fsprogs-libs-1.43.5-8.alios7.x86_64                                                                                       26/28
  Verifying  : krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                         27/28
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                    28/28

Installed:
  openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-23.1.alios7

Dependency Installed:
  keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64 0:1.5.8-3.4.alios7    krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.15.1-51.1.alios7         libcom_err-devel.x86_64 0:1.43.5-8.3.alios7
  libkadm5.x86_64 0:1.15.1-51.1.alios7             libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-14.1.1.alios7    libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-10.1.alios7
  libverto-devel.x86_64 0:0.2.5-4.1.alios7         pcre-devel.x86_64 0:8.32-15.1.alios7           zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.7-16.2.alios7

Dependency Updated:
  e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.43.5-8.3.alios7         e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.43.5-8.3.alios7        keyutils-libs.x86_64 0:1.5.8-3.4.alios7
  krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.15.1-51.1.alios7        libcom_err.x86_64 0:1.43.5-8.3.alios7            libselinux.x86_64 0:2.5-14.1.1.alios7
  libsepol.x86_64 0:2.5-10.1.alios7            libss.x86_64 0:1.43.5-8.3.alios7                 openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-23.1.alios7

Complete!
```

but the issue not solved. 
Please guide how to solve. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found this command:
`sudo yum install openssl` then it's solved my issue
Result:

```sh
s this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/2): openssl-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64.rpm                                                                              | 493 kB  00:00:00
(2/2): make-3.82-21.1.alios7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                   | 419 kB  00:00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                            1.9 MB/s | 912 kB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : 1:make-3.82-21.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                                1/2
  Installing : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           2/2
  Verifying  : 1:make-3.82-21.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                                1/2
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-23.1.alios7.x86_64                                                                                           2/2

Installed:
  openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-23.1.alios7

Dependency Installed:
  make.x86_64 1:3.82-21.1.alios7
```